# ASP.Net Membership user management from outside

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, membership

I actually want to create/list/edit asp.net membership users from a page authenticating with Windows-Authentication, the website uses ASP.Net MVC4. This is the administration website for another website using the forms authentication with asp.net membership on an SQL database. So this should allow company users to administer external users.

I can't use Membership-API, because the actual context does not support the asp.net membership.

Using the stored procedures requires manually hashing the password etc and this is not recommended. Also inserting the users directly into the tables would have this problem.

So is there a working example for administering asp.net membership users from a windows forms authenticated website?

Answer (score 0):

I just managed to solve this problem using a webservice to decouple Windows-Domain authentication from asp.net-Membership:

- Windows Domain Website for administration uses Webservice
- Webservice offers functionality to manage users of asp.net membership
- Webservice access has to be restricted to local server (so only the Windows Domain website can use it) and allows anonymous access (or with a special account).
- Webservice needs to be configured like an asp.net membership website and to use the same membership database like the "normal users Website"